# Dynamically generate a class in C# for SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am using Xamarin.Forms .Net Standard 1.4 library and the SQLite nuget.

I create classes for my database tables/records as follow:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Table("my_table")]
    public class MyRecord
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
        public int ID { get; set; } = -1;

        [Unique, NotNull, Column("GUID")]
        public Guid GUID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        public string Field1 { get; set; }

        public string Field1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I can create/insert the table/records with

```
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(db_file);  
    conn.CreateTable<MyRecord>();   
    var record = new MyRecord {
        Field1 = "test",
        Field2 = "test"
    };  
    conn.Insert(record);    
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

I find myself in the situation where one table does not have known columns at compile time, so I can't create a class to describe it.  Is there an easy way to dynamically generate a class?

Suppose that during runtime I need to create a table with the following columns (all text) "NewField1", "NewField2".  I realize I could generate the SQL command to data.  But I lose the convenience of the wrapper from SQLite.

I would like to dynamically create a class and add the Properties as needed so I could still use CreateTable<> and Insert(), etc.  Is this possible?  Would it be efficient?  Or am I better off just using a Dictionary and creating SQL commands.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you generate a table at runtime, why in the world do you to generate a wrapper around it? You're not going to get any compile-time benefits from that class (it's already too late for that you see).

Comment: I guess the benefit I see in the convenience of not having to generate SQL queries myself.  I'd like to use LINQ, etc